# View PDF in Browser, Edit in Acrobat

Tags: 2010, pdf

I'd like to have SharePoint handle PDFs in such a way that PDFs will open in a browser, but will Edit in Acrobat. It seems that I can have one or the other:

If the DOCICON.xml is configured to show:

```
<Mapping Key="pdf" Value="pdficon_small.gif" OpenControl="AdobeAcrobat.OpenDocuments" />
```

No *"Edit Document"* or *"Edit in Acrobat"* menu appears, but I am able to view the PDF in a browser. However, if my mapping looks like this:

```
<Mapping Key="pdf" Value="pdficon_small.gif" OpenControl="SharePoint.OpenDocuments" />
```

I can edit in Acrobat beautifully, and it works with the drop-down menu per document, but it won't display the PDF in the browser, even after changing the settings in Acrobat/Reader to **Edit -> Preferences -> Internet -> Display PDF in Browser** but will show the popup of "Read Only" or "Edit" radio buttons.

I've also tried to fool with the client-side application, on the list and the site collection to open documents in browser by default. No change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this by changing the entry in docicon.xml to

```
<Mapping Key="pdf" Value="pdficon_small.gif" OpenControl="SharePoint.OpenDocuments" />
```

And resetting IIS. How did I forget resetting IIS? Everything works now.

Also the other mapping setting doesn't work on those web applications using **https** so I had to use the `SharePoint.OpenDocuments` opencontrol.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to see if a permssion issue. Change the permission of the headers from the browser.
Please, go to the **Central Administration**, then **Manage Web Application**.
 Select the WebApp where you have the pdf files. Then Click on the Ribbon on **General Settings**, **General Settings** again.
In the PopUp, in the section **Browser File Handling**, click on **Permissive**. Click Ok and try again.
Cheers!

Comment: I've tried that.